# Why is "cc" null inside a commandButton's action in my Facelets composite component?

Tags: facelets, composite-component

I have a Facelets Composite component that includes, among other things, a commandButton:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ui:component xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
          xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite" 
          xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
          xmlns:nc="http://compositecomps.sss.evla.nrao.edu/jsf"
          xmlns:opt="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/opt"
          xmlns:undo="http://undo.sss.evla.nrao.edu/jsf"
          xmlns:n="http://sss.evla.nrao.edu/jsf"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<cc:interface>
  <cc:attribute name="value" type="edu.nrao.sss.tools.obsprep.bulkedit.BulkEditor"                      required="true"/>
  <cc:attribute name="loop"  type="edu.nrao.sss.tools.obsprep.uiactions.project.scan.ScanLoopUIActions" required="true"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
  <ui:param name="loop" value="#{cc.attrs.loop}"/>
  <ui:param name="val"  value="#{cc.attrs.value}"/>

  <ice:panelGroup id="wizStep1"
                  rendered="#{val.readyToSelect}">
    <nc:header value="select fields to filter on"/>
    <ice:commandButton value="#{val.nameField.value}" action="#{val.select}"/>
    <table cellpadding="5">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th><th>Field</th><th>Search For</th><th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <opt:bulkEditField value="#{val.nameField}">
          <f:facet name="summary">
            <ice:inputText value="#{val.nameField.value}"/>
          </f:facet>
        </opt:bulkEditField>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <ice:commandButton value="Select" action="#{val.select}"/>
  </ice:panelGroup>
</cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

I've changed the code  to use `val.nameField.value` as the label for the first command button to demonstrate the problem.

When I use this component in a page, it renders the button and a list of searchable fields below it.  If I change the value of the name field, the button label changes.

However, if I click the button, I get a target unreachable exception:

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /resources/components /opt/bulkEdit.xhtml @25,79 action="#{val.select}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'val' resolved to null
```

I feel like I must be missing something fundamental to how these composite components work.  This worked fine as a tag file under facelets/JSF 1.2.  In the process of upgrading to JSF 2.0, I wanted to move on to using composite components so I can have a defined interface.

If I stop using `<ui:param/>` and put `cc.attrs.value` in directly, it tells me that `cc` is null.

I thought this could be a bug in icefaces, but switching to plain `<h:commandButton/>` does the same thing.

Thanks for any advice you may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in ICEfaces 2.0. You have a UISeries (panelTabSet or dataTable) that contains the composite component. See http://jira.icesoft.org/browse/ICE-7142. It's fixed in 3.0.